# NoMethodError: undefined method `similaridade_com' for #<Class:0x007ff55873cad0> - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando criar um atributo da classe que será uma matriz de similaridade entre os usuários. Tem alguma coisa errada com essa construção? Tem um jeito melhor de ser feito?

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base

require 'matrix'

@@similaridade = Matrix.build( self.all.size, self.all.size) 
                          {|x,y| similaridade_com self.find(x + 1), self.find(y + 1) }

def self.similaridade
  @@similaridade
end

private

  def similaridade_com(usuario1, usuario2)
    ...
  end

end
```

Quando estou chamando `Usuario.similaridade` no `rails console` está dando o erro *NoMethodError: undefined method `similaridade_com' for #Class:0x007ff55873cad0*

Comment: Já tentou colocar `self.` na frente da chamada do método?

Comment: Você está usando uma variável de classe (@@similaridade) que quando é inicializada usa um método de instância (similaridade_com). Já tentou a dica do Andrey?

Answer (score 2):

Se não houver restrições, seria melhor criar uma tabela com a relação has_many through:

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :similaridades
  has_many :usuarios, through: :similaridades
end

class Similaridade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :usuario
  belongs_to :similar, :class_name => 'Usuario'
end
```

Assim você pode definir um método em 'usuario' como:

```
def similaridade_com(usuario)
  self.similaridades.find_by(similar: usuario)
end
```

Considerei que você usa pluralization em português, mas procure codificar sempre em inglês para aproveitar as convenções do Rails.

Comment: A ideia é deixar na memória para fazer menos acesso possível ao banco, uma vez que essas operações são muito demoradas, estava vendo em usar _Redis_, porém analisar se essa solução é viável uma vez que tenho pouco conhecimento...

Answer (score 0):

Você declarou esse método na seção `private`. Isso quer dizer que o [método é privado](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/advanced/private_methods.html). Métodos privados só podem ser chamados pelo próprio receptor, o `self`.

Se for para mérito de testes, use o `Object#send`. O que ele faz é chamar um método de uma instância de objeto, independente da visibilidade desse método (private, protected, public).

```
usuario = Usuario.new
usuario.send(:similaridade_com, param1, param2)
# => ...
```